# Showing a symlink as-is over an sshfs mount

Tags: sftp, sshfs, fuse

I have a filesystem on the host that contains symlinks (e.g. `/foo/bar -> /baz/bar`). I'm able to mount the filesystem over sshfs fine, but the symlink is resolved on the client, e.g. (they're mounted at the same location):

On the client (mounted with sshfs):

```
client $ ls -l /foo/bar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group 1234 May 28 14:03 /foo/bar
```

And on the server:

```
server $ ls -l /foo/bar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user group 73 May 27 19:16 /foo/bar -> /bar/baz
```

I have tried running sshfs directly, with no `-o follow_symlinks` arg, but the symlink continues to be presented as a file.

**How can I get the symlink to present as a symlink over sshfs?**

I have tried to the server via `sftp` directly, but it lists the file as a symlink (but with no target) - note the leading `l` at the start of the line:

```
$ sftp client
Connected to client.
sftp> cd /foo
sftp> ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx    1 user     group       73 May 27 19:16 bar
```

Could `follow_symlinks` be in an rc file somewhere on the server?

Answer (score 0):

I found that for my case, I had a number of filesystems at play.

e.g. I had:

```
/foo/bar -> /bar/baz
```

but I also had:

```
/foo -> /qux
```

and therefore the original symlink was:

```
/qux/baz -> /bar/baz
```

And `/foo`, `/bar` and `/qux` were all different filesystems. I had removed `-o follow_symlinks` from the `sshfs` mount in `/foo` but not `/qux`. Removing that also helped.